# How to get value of all inputs not type hidden

Tags: jquery

I want to clear value of all inputs but except input type hidden which contains some value I want to submit on server.

What is the best way to select all form fields in a form but ignore hidden fields in the selection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try selecting like this:

```
$(":input:not([type=hidden])")
```

You can refer more [here](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector) and [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) selectors like,

```
$('input:not(:hidden)').val('');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:not(:hidden)').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="one" /><br/>
<input type="text" value="two" /><br/>
<input type="hidden" value="one hidden" /><br/>
<input type="text" value="three" /><br/>
```

Comment: Quite strange selector `input:not:hidden]`

Comment: It was mistakenly placed, I've updated my answer with a snippet too.

Answer (score 2):

Select all input fields which are not hidden.

```
jQuery('input[type!=hidden]').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried 
$('input[type!=hidden]')
?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned inputs of a form:

```
  $('form input:not([type=hidden])')
```

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery selector worked for me. I am trying to get a list of all the fields inside a form that is an input element and is not a hidden input and is not a button

```
let formFields = jQuery('form.my-form').find(':input:not(:hidden):not(:button)');
```